# Selenium WebDriver set PhantomJS initial viewportSize using PhantomJSOptions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Using Selenium WebDriver under .net, when PhantomJS starts up, the default viewportSize is 400 px wide by 300 px high.  Is it possible to increase the default viewportSize using PhantomJSOptions *before* it is created?

Here is what I tried and it did not seem to have any effect:

```
    PhantomJSOptions opts = new PhantomJSOptions();

    opts.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.viewportSize", "{ width: 1024, height: 768 }");
```

Here is an alternative that works *after* the driver is created:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024,768);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the window size using WebDriver.

```
driver.set_window_size(1024,68)
```

If you really want to, perhaps this:

```
var phantomJSDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(phantomJsDir);
phantomJSDriverService.phantomjs.page.viewportSize = "{ width: 1024, height: 768 }";
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJSDriverService);
```

Comment: I'm looking to set the initial size on "driver" *before* it's created.  This solutions sets the size *after* creation.

Comment: I saw that.  But why?  The usual sequence is to create the browser instance, resize it, remove cookies, etc., then navigate somewhere. If you managed to do what you propose what would be gained?

Comment: two reasons (1) my usual sequence doesn't include resizing or cookies.  When I create a Chrome or Firefox instance, it's maximized and ready to go, so I'd like my PhantomJS instance to be reasonably-sized when I create it.  Also (2) I'd like to learn by example how to use PhantomJSOptions to specify PhantomJS settings I see in http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html

Comment: My chrome and firefox have to be maximized after creation but curiosity is a fine reason.